# C++ coalesce analogue

Tags: c++

In c# i can use the syntax `var c = a ?? b`
receiving the first variable other than null (for nullable variables of same type). This is similar to the coallesce operator in transact-sql
`DECLARE @c VARCHAR = COALESCE (@a, @b)`. Is there a way to write like this in C++?

Comment: There is no builtin way to do that, but writing a function for this purpose shouldn't be hard.

Comment: What's the type of `a` and `b`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: It's probably not what OP needs though.

Comment: a and b is nullable variables of same type

Comment: in your case, you could do
    
      auto c = a ? a : b;

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a built-in operator like that in C++. Moreover, in C++, there isn't some highly-common `null` value which you set variables to: Integers, floating-points and Boolean variables **cannot be `null`**.

We do have a special "vocabulary type" named [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), where an `std::optional<T>` can hold either a value of type `T` or an "empty" / "nullopt" value - which is similar to what other languages use `null` for.

If `a` and `b` are optionals (of the same type), you could write:

```
auto c = a.value_or(b);
```

<sub>Note: The above works common, non-lvalue-reference types. Also, it will get rid of the `optional<T>` wrapper, i.e. you won't be able to assign `nullopt` to the result.</sub>

Comment: there is a `value_or` function in optional: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value_or.

Comment: @perreal: Indeed. I was focusing on lvalue references, which `value_or()` doesn't handle.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are optionals of the same type, one could also write: `auto c = a ? a : b;` and retain the optional-ness.

Comment: Unfortunately, `value_or` cannot be used with throw expressions: `a.value_or(throw std::runtime_error("..."))`, a typical use case for a coalesce operator, does not compile. `a ? a : throw std::runtime_error("...")` works, but has type `std::optional<T>` when it could have type `T`, because the result cannot be empty.

Answer (score 1):

As [einpoklum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59438056/566849) stated, there's no generalized concept of *null variable* in C++, but the types that **do** support a *nullable state* tend to expose a common interface: they explicitly convert to `bool`, and in that conversion they result being `false` if *null*, `true` otherwise.

This happens with pointers, for instance, or types that expose a pointer-like interface, like `std::optional<T>`.

In all those circumstances, you can use the ternary operator to achieve the result you want:

`auto c = a ? a : b;`

Contrary to a *coalesce operator*, though, the ternary operator may evaluate its first operand twice. This is not an issue with pointers (smart or raw) or `std::optional<T>` and other types that explicitly and *const-ly* convert to bool, but might be an issue with other types that have side effects during the conversion (can't imagine one, at the moment, and I'd dare say that any non-const conversion to bool should be deemed faulty).

Gcc, however, [supports an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html), which lets you Not Repeat Yourself and avoid side effects. A true coalescing (*[elvis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator)*) operator:

`auto c = a ?: b;`

Which, incidentally, does seem to be quite the syntax you were looking for.

Comment: In `auto c = a ? a : b;`, if `a` is an r-value expression that has a side effect (or cost), such as a function call, then repeating it does matter, even if its type is a pointer, smart pointer or `std::optional`. For your statement to be true, `a` would have to be a variable that temporarily holds the result of such an expression.

Comment: I did state that expressions with side effects are an issue, with the ternary operator.

Comment: Fair enough. That's an even more general problem. Throw expressions are just one use case, but a very common one.

Comment: I guess to handle side effects properly, one would need a helper function that does something like `std::optional<T>::value_or` but takes a lambda. This would arguably be more cumbersome than an `if` statement but could be used in some places where an expression is needed, and it justifies a coalesce operator built into the language as syntactic sugar.